# Как добавить свой пункт меню в меню окна Java?

Tags: java, javafx

[image]

Вот в это меню хотелось бы добавить свое. Можно что-то изменить с помощью primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.***), но это не то. Это мне в основном для эксперимента, для знания. Просто в @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
}
именно Stage, поэтому свой класс отпадает. 
Как пересобрать класс Stage ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это за класс и кто это import com.sun.javafx.beans.annotations.Default ? 
где его взять ?
Я точно не помню, но вроде в swing или applet можно было это меню изменять.

Comment: Доступ к этому меню можно получить через WinAPI. Стандартными средствами JavaFX - нет.

Comment: Спасибо. Это jni, скомпилировать библиотеку, в эту сторону ?

Comment: JNA, установить из maven central